# How to add feature names to output of decision tree in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am building a decision tree in  scikit-learn then  want to produce a pdf of the tree.  My workflow to output the tree is roughly as follows.

```
vec = DictVectorizer()
data_vectorized = vec.fit_transform(data)
vec.get_feature_names() #Shows feature names

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(data_vectorized, Labels)

from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
import pydot 
dot_data = StringIO() 
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data) 
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()) 
graph.write_pdf("tree.pdf")
```

However each node of this pdf shows a comparison using data_vectorized[i] for some i. This is quite hard to interpret when data_vectorized is large and sparse.

How can I get it show the name of the feature instead?

This image shows an example of what you get  (when the features are in a variable X. I would like X[2], for example, to be replaced by the name of the feature.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your export to this:

```
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data, feature_names=vec.get_feature_names())
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have spotted that.